# Why are queries faster when subqueries within the WITH clause are duplicated?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Suppose a project uses partitions to structure its data. This concept is purely business specific and does not have to do with database partitioning.

Let's say the business logic does:

- delete from output_table where partition = < partitionX >
- insert into output_table (select * from input_table where partition = < partitionX >)

Keeping in mind that everything is structured like that, let's complicate a problem (to get to the actual question).

Suppose that I have a query (the SELECT query) that is potential killer, in terms of time :

```
insert into output_table (
  select * 
   from input_table
   left outer join additional_table additional_table1  
     on input_table.id = additional_table1.id
   left outer join additional_table additional_table2  
    on additional_table2.id = additional_table1.parent
  where partition =  <partitionX>
)
```

Let's optimize this and explore the options. **Keep in mind every table has partitions. Also notice how table2 is joined twice, but on different columns. And, also notice how the additional table is joined on itself**

Everything uses the WITH clause, but there are several options and I would like to know why one of these is better.

A. direct and duplicate queries in the WITH section

```
WITH 
CACHED_input_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM input_table
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
),
CACHED_additional_table1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM additional_table 
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
),
CACHED_additional_table2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM additional_table 
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
)
SELECT *    
FROM CACHED_input_table input_table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table1 additional_table1 
    ON input_table.ID = additional_table1.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table2 additional_table2 
    ON additional_table1.PARENT_ID = additional_table2.ID
```

B. reuse of query in the FROM section

```
WITH 
CACHED_input_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM input_table
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
),
CACHED_additional_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM additional_table 
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
)
SELECT *    
FROM CACHED_input_table input_table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table additional_table1 
    ON input_table.ID = additional_table1.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table additional_table2 
    ON additional_table1.PARENT_ID = additional_table2.ID
```

C. reuse of query in the WITH section

```
WITH 
CACHED_input_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM input_table
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
),
CACHED_additional_table1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM additional_table 
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
),
CACHED_additional_table2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM CACHED_additional_table1 
)
SELECT *    
FROM CACHED_input_table input_table

LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table1 additional_table1 
 ON input_table.ID = additional_table1.ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table2 additional_table2 
 ON additional_table1.PARENT_ID = additional_table2.ID
```

**From experience, Option A is the fastest. But why? Can someone explain this?**
(I am playing on Oracle v11.2)

*I know that, potentially, my optimization around this company specific concept of partitions has nothing to do with the generic sql optimization around WITH clause that I am asking about, but please take it as a real-life example.*

## Explain plans

**Option A** (9900 rows in 7s)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                              |     1 |  1037 | 18540   (8)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER        |                              |     1 |  1037 | 18540   (8)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER       |                              |     1 |   605 |  9271   (8)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE|                              |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | input_table                  |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |    24 |    24 |
|   5 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE|                              |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | additional_table             |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |    24 |    24 |
|   7 |   PARTITION LIST SINGLE |                              |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL    | additional_table             |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |    24 |    24 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("additional_table"."PARENT"="additional_table"."ID"(+))
   2 - access("input_table"."ID"="additional_table"."ID"(+))
```

**Option B** (9900 rows in 10s)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                              |     1 |  2813 | 18186  (11)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                              |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA2_C26AF925  |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE   |                              |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | additional_table1            |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |    24 |    24 |
|*  5 |   HASH JOIN OUTER          |                              |     1 |  2813 |  8939  (15)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|*  6 |    HASH JOIN OUTER         |                              |     1 |  1493 |  4470  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |     PARTITION LIST SINGLE  |                              |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL     | input_table                  |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |    24 |    24 |
|   9 |     VIEW                   |                              |  1362K|  1714M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA2_C26AF925  |  1362K|   561M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  11 |    VIEW                    |                              |  1362K|  1714M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  12 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA2_C26AF925  |  1362K|   561M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("additional_table1"."PARENT"="additional_table2"."ID"(+))
   6 - access("input_table"."ID"="additional_table1"."ID"(+))
```

**Option C** (9900 rows in 17s)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                              |     1 |  2813 | 18186  (11)| 00:00:03 |       |       |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION |                              |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA7_C26AF925  |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE   |                              |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | additional_table             |  1362K|   561M|  9248   (8)| 00:00:02 |    24 |    24 |
|*  5 |   HASH JOIN OUTER          |                              |     1 |  2813 |  8939  (15)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
|*  6 |    HASH JOIN OUTER         |                              |     1 |  1493 |  4470  (15)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   7 |     PARTITION LIST SINGLE  |                              |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL     | input_table                  |     1 |   173 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |    24 |    24 |
|   9 |     VIEW                   |                              |  1362K|  1714M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA7_C26AF925  |  1362K|   561M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  11 |    VIEW                    |                              |  1362K|  1714M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  12 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6CA7_C26AF925  |  1362K|   561M|  4447  (14)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("additional_table1"."PARENT_ID"="CACHED_additional_table"."ID"(+))
   6 - access("input_table"."ID"="additional_table1"."ID"(+))
```

***EDIT*** :

- added explain plans
- edited base query : there is an input_table, and an additional_table that is joined twice, once on input_table, and once on itself
- edited query for option A : there is an input_table, and the additional_table is joined twice, once on input_table, and once on a duplicate of itself (additional_table)
- edited query for Option B : there is an input_table, and the additional_table is joined twice, once on input_table, and once on itself, using the same alias(additional_table)
- edited query for Option C : there is an input_table, and the additional_table is joined twice, once on input_table, and once on another table created from itself in the WITH section

Comment: changing the table names and aliases does not alter the fact that option A reduces the size of tables to be joined, so option A is NOT equivalent to your baseline and probably why there is a performance gain. Not due to use of with, but due to use of further join conditions. please refer to my suggested answer for more

Comment: @Used_By_Already I am optimizing the baseline, so I do not want them to be the same (I think they do the same thing in end and I hope so). However, what I want is to compare options here

Comment: Thought you are trying to understand why "with" is apparently faster. To really figure that out you need to study equivalent queries.

Comment: did you reach a conclusion on this?

Comment: @Used_By_Already no, not as to why the observations are like they are. both option A and your optimization have good results and definitely show plans with less intermediate objects. i also did not try the inline-hint, as  I do not know what it means and how to do it (this needs more research and understanding on my side)

Comment: `Point 1` Your initial question did not compare apples to apples. Your "baseline" differs to Option A - so I tried firstly to steer you to an "equivalent" query (so you do compare apples to apples). `Point 2` Then my option B proposes that you do not need 3 CTEs,  just 1 CTE, and (imho) it is most likely to offer best performance (because the does the minimum numbers of things to achieve the result). `Conclusion`  If it isn't the best performing option I would learn by you selecting the best answer.

Comment: Point 1 : can't we focus on the inner select and forget about the outter insert?

Comment: Point 2 : I see there is less CTE in Option B however the explain plan shows more ( intermediate ) objects, and the performance is worse. Based on the explain plans and tests, Option B does not perform as expected. And this is part of my question : why is Option B worse (and maybe now with the explain plans in place it would be better to ask : why is option B constructing more objects) ?

Comment: `Point 1` I already did. `Point 2` ok, but you have your answer I see `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query A has to read three partitions, one partition of input_table and two times a single partition of additional_table.

Query B has to read two partitions, one partition of input_table and one partition of additional table. Then, it has to write that one partition to a temporary table and read that temporary table twice.

So, assuming the estimates are ok:
Query A reads 1 row in the partition of input_table
+ 2 times 1362K rows in additional_table

Query B reads 1 row in the partition of input_table
+ 3 times 1362K rows in additional_table + the temporary table
+ writes 1362K rows.

If the optimizer decides to materialize your factored subqueries, you're off worse. You can prevent materializing by using the inline-hint, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the ability to materialize the subqueries defined in the with clause, if it feels that it is beneficial to do so. Generally (but not necessarily always!), it'll do that if you refer to the same subquery more than once in the main query.

When Oracle materializes a subquery, it runs the sql and then stores the results in a global temporary table behind-the-scenes. Then for subsequent calls, it queries the temporary table.

In your case, I can see that option A repeats the same query as a subquery - you'd have to check the execution plans to see what Oracle is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: I would expect, based on your answer, that Option B would win in terms on run-time. However, as soon as I do that second join on the same sub-query, time goes up quite a lot.

Comment: I would expect the same thing too! Can you edit your question to include the explain plans of all three options, please? That ought to give a clue as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Common Table Expressions (the WITH clause) should be very much similar to a normal select with joins/sub queries when no recursive is being used(After all, that's their purpose). Perhaps it can optimize two references to the same table better.

You would have to use the actual execution plan to find any differences, and that would be specific to your setup so it's hard to answer that question.

I doubt there will be any significantly differences between those queries, but (I assume Oracle) you can use another thing to optimize an `INSERT` - [`APPEND` hint](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint) :

```
INSERT /* + APPEND */ INTO YourTable
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into output_table (
  select * 
   from input_table
   left outer join additional_table additional_table1  
     on input_table.id = additional_table1.id
   left outer join additional_table additional_table2  
    on additional_table2.id = additional_table1.parent
  where partition =  <partitionX>
)
```

If the above is your baseline, then  option A is NOT exactly equivalent. The following would be closer i think.

```
insert into output_table (
  select * 
   from input_table
   left outer join additional_table additional_table1  on input_table.id = additional_table1.id
             and additional_table1.partition =  <partitionX>
   left outer join additional_table additional_table2 on additional_table2.id = additional_table1.parent
             and additional_table2.partition =  <partitionX>
  where partition =  <partitionX>
)
```

The point being the in option A you have decreased the sizes of derived tables to be joined. In the baseline that is not true.

B.1. Single CTE as basis of both joins

```
WITH 
CACHED_additional_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM additional_table 
  WHERE PARTITION_ID = < partition  X >
)
SELECT *    
FROM input_table input_table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table additional_table1 
    ON input_table.ID = additional_table1.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CACHED_additional_table  additional_table2 
    ON additional_table1.PARENT_ID = additional_table2.ID
```

The difference between this variant and option B is that you are only caching a single query result, then using that single common table expression (CTE) twice  in the main query. This is a good use case for CTEs (avoiding repetition).

Comment: let me edit the base line to better match my detailed queries analized

Comment: also, your suggestion was the initial optimization : an extra clause in the JOIN parts to contain the filtering part, but I hope the WITH examples are better optmized

Comment: I also run this again (your optimization suggestion) and it does 9900 rows in 7s, which is very good I would say

Comment: do a single CTE on additional_table fitered on partition then join it twice.

Comment: but that is Option B which is worse then Option A and your suggestion

Comment: No. Option b.1 qhich is only a single CTE.  I cannot test it but that looks to  me to be your best option.